# Cannot setup Inherited class's method as slot for click signal

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

So basically I inherited from QPushButton and I want to handle the signal right inside the class. I also promoted the button I want to this new class.

So I did:

```
QObject::connect(ui->pickWatermarkButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),ui->pickWatermarkButton, SLOT(handleButton()));
```

The handleButton exists and is declared as a public slot. However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

I changed the slot to a location function, inside mainWindow, and surprise, it works! Apparently it only refuses to work when I try to use as a slot a method in the inherited class!

Comment: Make sure there is `Q_OBJECT` macro in your button class and that `handleButton()` is declared in the `slots:` section.

Comment: As LogicStuff said. If it’s not the missing Q_OBJECT macro, add your QPushButton subclass header here. Also, check the console for errors from the connect() call.

Comment: I added the Q_OBJECT macro. But now I get "undefined reference to vtable" errors. And yes, I defined a destructor!

Comment: Right clicking on the project and selectin "run qmake" fixed that undefined reference to vtable error.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, just add the Q_OBJECT macro to your inherited class.

If you get "undefined reference to vtable" compilation errors, make sure you defined a destructor. If they still appear, right click on your project and select "run qmake", and then build your project again.